# Start date pushed back because I didn't meet an address verification deadline that wasn't stated

Tags: deadlines, start-date

I'm in the process of moving and had an email coming in last Monday for confirming my address so my work equipment would arrive on time. I figured I could get back to them a week before my start date aka this week. The problem was that the deadline was in that last Friday, but it was never stated in the email that there was a deadline. I'm annoyed that there was a deadline that was never stated that pushed back my start date. Do I go to my recruiter, manager, HR?

Comment: "*Do I go to my recruiter, manager, HR?*" To do what? What is the question here? Presumably you need to talk to your (new) company to sort this out. I'm not sure what else people here can help with?

Comment: "I figured I could get back to them a week before my start date aka this week. " - Sounds like you made an assumption that ended up being wrong. Maybe clarify next time, "I want to verify when I need to give you my new address? I am hoping to relay it to you a week before my start date." And everything would have been resolved without guessing.

Comment: VTC because it sounds like a company policy that you didn't get clarification on. All you can do at this point is tell them you want the job and didn't realize there was a deadline. I'm sure they won't be very happy that you are that chill that you won't even ask when something might be due though.

Comment: Why would you wait a week to respond to a simple email from your new employer asking to confirm your address?

Comment: How far back did it push your start date? Why not just ask any/all of them now?

Answer (score 2):

#### Just move on

Complaining about company practices is a poor way to start a new job.  Feel free to bring it up after you've been there a while to improve the process, but not yet.

As to why it didn't get done, don't "figure" you can wait to do things.